# Creating a custom error page in Umbraco CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco

I'm working on a client site who is using Umbraco as a CMS. I need to create a custom 404 error page. I've tried doing it in the IIS config but umbraco overrides that.

Does anyone know how to create a custom 404 error page in Umbraco?
Is there a way to create a custom error page for runtime errors?

Answer (score 18):

In `/config/umbracoSettings.config` modify `<error404>1</error404>` "*1*" with the id of the page you want to show.

```
<errors>
   <error404>1</error404> 
</errors>
```

Other ways to do it can be found at [Not found handlers](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/how-to-implement-your-own-404-handler)

Comment: You can find the page ID by going to the Umbraco admin, and looking at the status when hovering over the page.

Comment: The page ID is on the properties tab on the content section.

Answer (score 9):

As stated by other posters, modify the errors section as indicated (including culture if needed.) In addition, add the following in the web config to enable passthrough of errors to umbraco:

In /config/umbracoSettings.config (the file itself explains its usage):

```
<errors>
  <!-- the id of the page that should be shown if the page is not found -->
  <!--        <errorPage culture="default">1</errorPage>-->
  <!--        <errorPage culture="en-US">200</errorPage>-->
  <error404>2664</error404>
</errors>
```

In /web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <!-- Some other existing stuff -->
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

(Note: This is .NET 4)

Answer (score 8):

umbraco also supports culture dependent error pages in case you're working with multilingual sites...

Config changes a tiny bit. Instead of

```
<errors>
  <error404>1050</error404>
</errors>
```

you'd now write

```
<errors>
  <errorPage culture="default">1</errorPage>-->
  <errorPage culture="en-US">200</errorPage>-->
</errors>
```

Cheers,
/Dirk

Answer (score 1):

First create an error page (and template) in your umbraco installation. Let us say error.aspx. Publish it. 
Then edit **config/umbracoSettings.config**.

```
Under <errors> section
    <error404>1111</error404>
```

Where **1111** is the **umbraco node ID** for the error.aspx page

Node ID can be found by hovering mouse on the error node in **content** section. It's usually a 4 digit number.

Then edit the **web.config**:

```
    In <appSettings> section
    change <customErrors mode as show below:
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx"/>
```

Comment: appSettings section doesn't have a customErrors child. Also, you don't need to modify customErrors, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Currently `umbracoSettings.conf` has to be configured the following way in order to make it work in a multilingual way:

```
    <errors>
        <!-- the id of the page that should be shown if the page is not found -->
        <!--        <errorPage culture="default">1</errorPage>-->
        <!--        <errorPage culture="en-US">200</errorPage>-->
        <error404>
            <errorPage culture="default">1</errorPage>
            <errorPage culture="ru-RU">1</errorPage>
            <errorPage culture="en-US">2</errorPage>
        </error404>
    </errors>
```

Please note the `error404` element which surrounds the `errorPage` elements, as well as the comments omitting this small yet important detail...